xRDP fails to start
I have been working with RDP to a logged in and locked screen via both RemotePC and MS RDP.
However, I was reading that to be able to login from a rebooted/no-login it would require xRDP to be installed.  I attempted to do so, and when I tried to start xRDP, Ubuntu generated a failed to start message.  The information provided is (to me) about as clear as mud - very much a newbie, so I don't have any idea as to what this is indicating as the fault or what my next step should be.
Below is the journalctl entry:
The job identifier is 5766.
Dec 18 12:34:19 Ubuntu01 xrdp[121129]: [INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 1

Dec 18 12:34:19 Ubuntu01 xrdp[121129]: [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0

Dec 18 12:34:19 Ubuntu01 xrdp[121129]: [ERROR] g_tcp_bind(7, 3389) failed bind IPv6 (errno=98) a>

Dec 18 12:34:19 Ubuntu01 xrdp[121129]: [ERROR] trans_listen_address failed

Dec 18 12:34:19 Ubuntu01 xrdp[121129]: [ERROR] Failed to start xrdp daemon, possibly address alr>

Dec 18 12:34:19 Ubuntu01 systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1>

░░ Subject: Unit process exited

░░ Defined-By: systemd

░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

░░ 
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit xrdp.service has exited.

░░ 
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.

Dec 18 12:34:19 Ubuntu01 systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

░░ S```ubject: Unit failed

░░ Defined-By: systemd

░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

░░ 
░░ The unit xrdp.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.

Dec 18 12:34:19 Ubuntu01 systemd[1]: Failed to start xrdp daemon.

░░ Subject: A start job for unit xrdp.service has failed

░░ Defined-By: systemd

OK, quick follow-up. I saw the IPV6 error in the log and decided to disable the IPV6 protocol on the network card. xRDP status indicates it is running now (I don't know why it was trying to bind to IPV6 to start with), however it is still generating several errors that I don't understand:
xrdp.service - xrdp daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/xrdp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-12-18 12:54:31 CST; 4min 38s ago
       Docs: man:xrdp(8)
             man:xrdp.ini(5)
    Process: 952 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh /usr/share/xrdp/socksetup (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 1069 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/xrdp $XRDP_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1097 (xrdp)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18778)
     Memory: 2.0M
        CPU: 89ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/xrdp.service
             └─1097 /usr/sbin/xrdp

Dec 18 12:56:18 Ubuntu01 xrdp[1097]: [INFO ] Socket 12: AF_INET6 connection received from ::ffff:192.168.50.> 

Dec 18 12:56:18 Ubuntu01 xrdp[10629]: [INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem

Dec 18 12:56:18 Ubuntu01 xrdp[10629]: [INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem

Dec 18 12:56:20 Ubuntu01 xrdp[10629]: [ERROR] SSL_accept: I/O error
Dec 18 12:56:20 Ubuntu01 xrdp[10629]: [ERROR] trans_set_tls_mode: ssl_tls_accept failed
Dec 18 12:56:20 Ubuntu01 xrdp[10629]: [ERROR] xrdp_sec_incoming: trans_set_tls_mode failed
Dec 18 12:56:20 Ubuntu01 xrdp[10629]: [ERROR] xrdp_rdp_incoming: xrdp_sec_incoming failed
Dec 18 12:56:20 Ubuntu01 xrdp[10629]: [ERROR] xrdp_process_main_loop: libxrdp_process_incoming failed
Dec 18 12:56:20 Ubuntu01 xrdp[10629]: [ERROR] xrdp_iso_send: trans_write_copy_s failed
Dec 18 12:56:20 Ubuntu01 xrdp[10629]: [ERROR] Sending [ITU T.125] DisconnectProviderUltimatum failed


I'd edit your question a bit to use the triple tick <```> around the log output but alas not enough rep yet. You either have an SSH/SSL error going on or the user you attempted to login with an account that is not an authorized user on the Windows Machine that you're attempting to log into.
